# Add text to another file on top of it without overwriting anything in php

Tags: php

I want add 3 to 4 lines to all my files of my website, I am able to modify all php files

```
 $source = file_get_contents($path);
 $source = str_replace($this->oldTxt, '', $source); 
 $source = preg_replace('#\<\?php#',"<?php\n".$this->newTxt,$source,1);
 file_put_contents($path, $source);
 echo $path."\n";
```

By this code i am able to modify php files as they are starting with ?php, but what can i do add the same text to js and others text file on the top of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the text to all files on top

```
$source = file_get_contents($path);
file_put_contents($path, $this->newTxt . $source);
```

Any special reason, you insert the text after the <?php ?? The comment syntax is different in PHP, Javascript and HTML. So probably you need to adjust the text you include based on the file type.